# Using Gstreamer to stream GL framebuffer in realtime over HTTP

Tags: qt, gstreamer

I know the command line equivalents to stream media over tcp but they require a source of some sorts.

This command streams an image file,

`gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=output.jpg ! videoconvert ! tcpserversink port=8085`

To stream a camera / testvideo, we need to do something like,

`gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! convertvideo ! tcpserversink port=8085`

`gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! convertvideo ! tcpserversink port=8085`

The question may be more GStreamer specific for now but I'm looking to integrate QtGStreamer in my next step. Coming to the point, I need to know how to build a Gstreamer pipeline (Especially the video source) that takes feed from the GL framebuffer and streams it over http/tcp.

What to use in place of `filesrc` or `videotestsrc` in my cocoa app? Almost all the examples that I've seen are mostly getting source feed from a camera or a file and not from the memory (Framebuffer).

Since my application does screen casting, it is not feasible to write every frame to a file and feed it to the pipeline and I believe Gstreamer doesn't support it for live updates since
`filesrc` doesn't have a `is-live` parameter like `videotestsrc` so it doesn't update the frames even if the files are changed in the output file.

How to use GStreamer wrappers to stream framebuffer data in realtime (without writing it to a file)?

Comment: The question is more of GStreamer. You need to specify the pipeline with the lowest latency possible. Whether or no there is `latency` parameter for one of pipeline items, is also a question: may or may not be implemented so you need to look for such filters such `rtpsrc` but what kind of pipeline needed? It is too hard to guess and depends. What QtGStreamer does is creating some classes especially implementing GStreamer `sink` to render via Qt but does not change GStreamer itself. And why ObjectiveC here, I cannot tell.

Comment: Apologies @AlexanderVX. I've edited the question and added some more clarity on it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: This sounds like it is related http://blog.qt.io/blog/2017/07/07/qt-webgl-streaming-merged/

Comment: @dtech I looked into it, but it seems to differ from what I'm trying to achieve. I'm not even talking about interactions and GUI for now. I just want to stream my OpenGL framebuffer to the web in realtime. And I'm open to any kind of solution, not just sticking to Qt or GStreamer.

Comment: Now examine all the pipeline components docs (easy to find on the Internet).

Comment: Been trying that for more than a day. The gstreamer docs are not really helping. I don't get to see anything other than some hierarchy of plugins. I posted this here since I couldn't land on a proper solution. Here I'm talking about raw bytes from memory as source.

Comment: I also would try to replace one GStreamer plugin with another. GStreamer as technology can be applied having good plugins. Not much beyond that. The latency in the app itself is not that much other than there is really poor code there.

Comment: I wrote a program StereoCamCheck a few years ago that took a camera video stream over HTTP, through a GStreamer pipeline, and into an OpenGL texture. https://github.com/apertus-open-source-cinema/stereo_cam_check